# Is it possible to write a script that would intercept HTTP requests on HAproxy with the purpose of appending client side pki certificates?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, haproxy, cypress

I am a test engineer that is new to the game - 3 years experience - so sorry if I am not coming across as a technical wizard :) Would ask that you be patient with me, I'm also here to learn so happy to be corrected/ridiculed.

Due to the sensitivity of our applications, we are working with client side PKI certificates. These need to be loaded by the user into the browser if the application can be accessed. I was wondering if it would be possible that instead of having to import test certificates into the test browser we could instead append our test user pki certificates using HAproxy? Which we could then use to forward on the request to the applications reverse proxy?

A bit more context, we are looking to possibly move from Selenium to Cypress.io. Selenium is able to load the certificates into the browser in a @before test setup. Sadly Cypress doesn't play nice even when PKI certificates are manually loaded into the Cypress.IO chrome browser. I have included a link to someone who has the exact same problem below.

[cypress - 403 forbidden error when visiting main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143873/cypress-403-forbidden-error-when-visiting-main-site)

As a team we all really like Cypress but we fear this could be a blocker. I feel like if it was possible to do what I proposed with HAproxy then this could be a solid work around for our lower test environments.

Comment: " intercept http requests with the sole purpose of appending SSL certificates"  TLS (and hence HTTPS) does not work like this, you do not append "SSL" certificates to HTTP request there is a full specific handshake with cryptography negotiation. You are explicitely stating not wanting to give any context, that is your right but then the way you present the problem shows some low level problems that no answers will be able to address I fear.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for your advice I have edited accordingly so hopefully my problem makes a bit more sense. Would really appreciate your thoughts on this.